# multidimensional arrays (matrixes) in C and how to handle them

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I am working with creating a C code for accelerometer board to fill up buffers with axis data. I have two different accelerometers which provide X, Y and Z axis data, so 6 different data. I would like to keep all this data inside arrays, but having 6 different arrays is not very good solution, so I am thinking to use 3 multidimensional arrays: 2 rows, 32 colons. The problem is that I don't really know how to handle them, because I need to pass these buffers to a function as a reference:
`bool run_detect_movement (int16_t *X_buffer, int16_t *Y_buffer, int16_t *Z_buffer)`

No big deal here, but inside this function things get a bit trickier, I need to pass first row to one function and second row to other function so two different accelerometers data would be saved in one buffer.

`void Read_FIFO_packet_16_IIM (int16_t *X_buffer, int16_t *Y_buffer, int16_t *Z_buffer)`

`void Read_FIFO_packet_8_LIS (int16_t *X_buffer, int16_t *Y_buffer, int16_t *Z_buffer)`

So I am not really sure how to do it. here is an example of simplified main.c:

```
in16_t x_buffer_arrays[2][32] = {0};
in16_t y_buffer_arrays[2][32] = {0};
in16_t z_buffer_arrays[2][32] = {0};

int main()
{
    run_detect_movement (x_buffer_arrays, y_buffer_arrays, z_buffer_arrays);
    return 0;
}
```

here is accelerometer.h file content

```
bool   run_detect_movement (int16_t *X_buffer, int16_t *Y_buffer, int16_t *Z_buffer);
void   Read_FIFO_packet_8_LIS (int16_t *X_buffer, int16_t *Y_buffer, int16_t *Z_buffer);
void   Read_FIFO_packet_16_IIM (int16_t *X_buffer, int16_t *Y_buffer, int16_t *Z_buffer);
```

here is accelerometer.c file:

```
bool run_detect_movement (int16_t *X_buffer, int16_t *Y_buffer, int16_t *Z_buffer) {
    /*
        Do some stuff here
    */
    Read_FIFO_packet_16_IIM(X_buffer, Y_buffer, Z_buffer);
    Read_FIFO_packet_8_LIS(X_buffer, Y_buffer, Z_buffer);
    
}
```

is it possible to pass multidimensional arrays as a pointer to a function but with specific colon or row? I was thinking something similar to this:

```
&(X_buffer[1][])
```

And another question is how these arrays are filling up? If I am going to pass multidimensional array to a function which handles regular array, will it fill buffer or will I get error?

Comment: Use an array of struct, not a multidimensional array.

Comment: good idea, I will use that for now

Comment: The address of the second row (with index 1) of `X_buffer` is simply `&X_buffer[1]`, not `&(X_buffer[1][])`. However, the type of `&X_buffer[1]` is a pointer an array of 32 `int16_t`. To pass the address to a routine expecting an `int16_t *`, you want the address of the first element of the second row, which is `&X_buffer[1][0]`. And, since an array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, you can use `X_buffer[1]`, which is nominally the array that is the first row but will be converted to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Why the c++ tag?

Comment: project is written in c and c++, so maybe it is easier to handle these arrays in c++, I have never used them and it won't be a problem to adapt solution if it is in c++.

Comment: Why not use a 3d array by packing all dimensions into a single object: `void foo(int n, int16_t arr[3][2][n])` ?